# How to use RegExp in DataTables' searchCols?

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

How is one supposed to use regular expressions in the [searchCols](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchCols) option of Datatables 1.10 and above? It filters fine for normal strings, but does not work for regular expressions, as far as I can tell.

Here is some code (full example at http://live.datatables.net/bahejesi/1/edit):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "/ssp/server_processing.php",
      searchCols: [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { search: "(London|New York)", "escapeRegex": false },
        null,
        null
      ]
    } );
} );
```

Eventually, what I want to achieve is to filter my table based on input from the query string (e.g., id = a OR b, id <= c). (Not sure the latter part can be achieved with RegExp.)

Another option would be the API [filter()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) function. But I don't know how to integrate that with the example code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the documentation on `searchCols` is not very clear. Each element of `searchCols` behaves just as [`search`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search) itself does. So, adding [`"regex": true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.regex) as an option does the job. Not sure what `"escapeRegex": false` does in this case. It does not seem to have any effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "/ssp/server_processing.php",
      searchCols: [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "search": "^S", "regex": true },
        null,
        null
      ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: `escapeRegex` is just a helper function to escape special characters in a regular expression string -> http://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(). Remember to accept your own answer, perhaps helping other people in the future. +1 for self answering.

Comment: Ok, so it escapes user input that is to be used in a regular expression. Thanks for the clarification. Will accept when I am allowed to - tomorrow.